# Why do I have to return app in Flask create_app?

Tags: web, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import config

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
mail = Mail()
moment = Moment()
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    # 
    return app
```

Hi, I'm learning Flask by reading 'Flask Web Development by Grinberg M'.
The above code is copied from that book.

Could anyone please explain why I need to "return app" in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you haven't copied the complete code.

You've probably missed these lines or something similar:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app('Example')
    app.run()
```

The reason the author returns the *app*, as @davidism has explained, is that we use the app instance to start our Flask application. Simple as that!

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Did you check and see if you had missed some lines? I'm glad it has helped.

Comment: By the way, would you tell me why the variables such as mail.init_app(app) exits even if they have not been returned? Or what's the keyword I need to search for learning this part of knowledge?

Comment: For more information about application factories you can see here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/appfactories/

Comment: yes, that just is part of the whole code which the author use to describe how to create app by using factory function. I have stuck in this part and have not read the rest of codes yet, actually, there is another part "blue print" I need to go through.

Comment: Yes. You'll definitely need Flask Blueprints. If you're new to flask, this tutorial is really helpful http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world